# Should using torque formula lead to similar results as force formula when calculating the tangential acceleration?

Tags: classical-mechanics

using summation of torque equals rate of change of angular momentum
*t=Ia* with *t=m*g*cos(angle)*1* where the angle is the angle from the horizontal to the door, and 1 is the position of the center of mass.
*I=1/3 *m*r^2*; where r is the radius to the point we are studying from the origin
I am considering a thin rectangular shape for this derivation
http://gauss.vaniercollege.qc.ca/pwiki/images/1/15/Rot_KE_Mom_Inertia_7.png

*a* is the angular acceleration.

Now solving that resulted in *a=gcos(angle)*3/r^2*

---

For the second method, I worked the problem using force equal mass times acceleration.

*f=m*g*cos(angle)=m*a(linear tangential acceleration)*
therefore; *m*g*cos(angle)=m*r*a(angular acceleration)* ; where r is the distance from the center of mass to the origin. 
That means the angular acceleration equals,
which results in,  *a=g*cos(angle)*

---

Both ways makes a lot of sense to me so I am not really sure which one is correct and why?

Comment: a=gcos(angle)3/r^2 is dimensionally incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If the door is pivoted at the hinges then when an external force is applied on the door there will also be another force on the door due to the hinges.
If you consider torques about the hinges those forces acting at the hinges make no contribution to the torque on the door about the hinges.
Only the torque due to the applied force acting on the door needs to be included to find the angular acceleration.
However when considering the linear acceleration of the centre of mass of the door both the applied force on the door and the force due to the hinges on the door must be included when applying Newton's second law.